# Allow user to specify a Backbone model's ID at creation time

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

When saving a model, Backbone determines whether to send an HTTP `POST` or `PUT` request by whether or not the model's ID attribute is set. If there is an ID, the model is considered to already exist.

For my application, this logic is incorrect because I must allow the user to specify an ID (as I interact with a poorly designed legacy system).

How should I handle this problem? I still would like to use `PUT` if the model is changed.

I am considering the following options:

1. Override `isNew`, which is the Backbone method that simply checks if an ID is present.
2. Override `sync`.
3. Determine if the concept of `cid` would somehow solve the problem.

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to address the symptoms rather than the cause.  Consider adding to your model a new `create` method:

```
var FooModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/api/foo',
  create: function () {
     return this.save(null, { 
         type: 'post', // make it a POST rather than PUT
         url: this.urlRoot // send the request to /api/foo rather than /api/foo/:id
     });
  }
});
```

This is the solution I use, but I don't consider it ideal because the view logic/caller now needs to call `create` rather than `save` when creating (which is rather easy to do).  This extended API bothers me for my use-case (despite working and being rather small), but perhaps it'll work for yours.

I'd love to see some additional answers to this question.

Comment: Maybe you could override "save" instead adding "create".

Comment: @DonaldTaylor But then how do you NOT perform the POST override on edits?

Answer (score 1):

So I went down the path of trying to change up `isNew`.

I came up with new criteria that would answer whether a model is new:

1. **Was the model created via a fetch from a collection?** Then it's definitely not new.
2. **Was the model created with an ID attribute?**  This is a choice I made for my case, see disadvantages below for the effect of doing this, but I wanted to make `new Model({ id: 1, name: 'bob' })` not be considered new, while setting the ID later on (`new Model({ name: 
   bob'}).set('id', 1)`) would be.
3. **Was the model ever synced?** If the model was successfully synced at any point, it's definitely not new because the server knows about it.

Here's what this looks like:

```
var UserDefinedIDModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // Properties

  _wasCreatedWithID: false,
  _wasConstructedByFetch: false,
  _wasSynced: false,

  // Backbone Overrides

  idAttribute: 'some_id',

  urlRoot: '/api/foo',

  constructor: function (obj, options) {
    this._wasCreatedWithID = !!obj[this.idAttribute];
    this._wasConstructedByFetch = options && options.xhr && options.xhr.status === 200;

    // Preserve default constructor
    return Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  },

  initialize: function () {
    this.on('sync', this.onSync.bind(this));
  },

  isNew: function () {
    // We definitely know it's not new
    if (this._wasSynced || this._wasConstructedByFetch) return false;

    // It might be new based on this.  Take your pick as to whether its new or not.
    return !this._wasCreatedWithID;
  },

  // Backbone Events

  onSync: function () {
    this._wasSynced = true;
  }
});
```

**Advantages over the other answers**

- No logic outside of the backbone model for handling this odd usecase.
- No server-side changes to support this
- No new pseudo properties

**Disadvantages**

- This is a lot of code when you could just create a new `create` method as per my other answer.
- Currently `myCollection.create({ some_id: 'something' });` issues a PUT.  I think if you need support for this you'll have to do `myCollection.create({ some_id: 'something' }, { url: '/api/foo', type: 'post' });`  You can remove the _wasCreatedWithoutID check to fix this, but then any construction of a new model that derives its data from an existing one will be treated as new (in my case, this is undesirable).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution :

In your model define an idAttribute that don't exists in your server model/table/... and that wouldn't be displayed to the DOM.

So let's suppose that the JSON that you send to the server is as follows :

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'My name',
    'description': 'a description'
}
```

Your model should look like :

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'fakeId'
});
```

Now, when you create a new model and try to save it to the server, no one would initialize the `fakeId` and it would be considered a new object (POST).

When you fetch your model from the server you have to set the fakeId in your model, and your server must duplicate the `id` in the `fakeId` like this your model will be considered as an existing (PUT)

Comment: Sweet timing as I'm dealing with this problem now myself.  I don't like this solution because if ID is editable, you now need to keep these two in sync and your server now needs to be aware of this limitation in Backbone.  Not sure what the fix should be, but it should be wholly contained within Backbone.